# Where's the error in my working for 'how many digits can be formed with...'?

Tags: combinatorics

> You form a 3-digit number using 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7. You can't use the numbers more than once. How many distinct even numbers can be formed that are $<289$?

My answer is 24, the correct answer is 25. Where have I gone wrong?

Three even numbers. Therefore, 3.

$<289$, i.e. first digit is less than or equal to 2. So, there are 2 numbers we can use.

Used the numbers 1 and 2 and one even number, so we're left with 4 numbers less than 8.

Therefore, $3×2×4=24$.

Clarification appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because 2 is an even number, things are different after the choice of the first digit.

- *First digit is 1*: We have three choices for the last digit (2, 4, 6) and five choices for the middle digit.
- *First digit is 2*: We have only *two* choices (4, 6) for the last digit and five choices for the middle digit.

Thus there are $3×5+2×5=25$ admissible numbers.

Comment: Thanks! So, let's say it asked for distinct odd numbers instead. Would it be 3x5 + 4x5? @Parcly Taxel

Comment: @MathsHelp Yes.